# SQL Server : Join Ignores Leading Zeros

Tags: sql-server, join

My question is pretty straight forward, so I'm going to attempt asking it without making any dummy tables.

Consider the case where I have two tables: A and B.

Suppose that A has `varchar` column `AVar` such that every element in `AVar` is a string of integers which do not begin with `0`.

Also suppose that B has a `varchar` column `BVar` such that the elements of `BVar` are identical to the entries in `AVar`, but have either 1 or 2 leading `0`'s in front of each entry.

For example "123454" in AVar would have a corresponding "0123454" or "00123454" in BVar

When I perform the following query I find that my join runs successfully, even though the `varchar` elements within the two tables are technically not the same string values.

What is happening under the hood that allows this comparison to be relaxed?

```
SELECT 
    A.AVar, B.BVar
FROM 
    A 
LEFT JOIN 
    B ON A.AVar = B.BVar
```

Comment: Are you sure the columns aren't being converted to INT anywhere in code?

Comment: Are you sure `AVar` is `VARCHAR` and not an `int`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, I'm confident that the original data tables have varchar data types.

Comment: @M.Ali, before making the join, I actually move these tables into temporary tables, but I make no edit to the type of those columns as I store them into the temp table. If there is an implicit conversion happening that is the only place it could be

Comment: well if the implicit conversion is converting it to INT then the leading zeros are irrelvant and both string `"0123"` and `"00123"` will become `"123"`

Comment: @M.Ali When I do a select statement from the resulting join, the variables appear untouched. So BVar still shows leading zeros in the resulting table.

Comment: This screams show me the query plan.

Comment: Can you include a short but complete example with sql code that reproduces the problem. What you have told us so far is not reproducible: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3a36/1

Comment: can you try with `A.AVar  like  B.BVar `

Comment: if you are joining this to a temp table, and the temp table has stored this string as an int, when you join sql server will do an implicit conversion again, Int being the higher presedence data type the variable will be converted to int too. Cannot help you unless you provide a dummy table in your question and reproduce the problem here.

Comment: @M.Ali, you are correct. I've found where the implicit conversion is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Server does an implicit conversion

this

```
select * from (
select 1  a , '00001' b union all
select 1  a , '1' b ) x
where x.b = x.a
```

produces

```
a   b
1   00001
1   1
```

while this

```
select * from (
select 1  a , '00001' b union all
select 1  a , '1' b ) x
where x.b like x.a
```

produces

```
a   b
1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use the `CONVERT()` or `CAST()` Methods. See below:

Using the `CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT
     CONVERT(NUMERIC,A.AVar)A.AVar, 
     CONVERT(NUMERIC,B.BVar)B.AVar
FROM A LEFT JOIN B
ON A.AVar = B.BVar
```

Using the `CAST()`:

```
SELECT
    CAST(A.AVar AS NUMERIC)A.AVar, 
    CAST(B.BVar AS NUMERIC)B.AVar
FROM A LEFT JOIN B
ON A.AVar = B.BVar
```